# Java entity, driver manager is not initialized

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I can't resolve `Java entity, driver manager is not initialized` in 3 days and I'm stuck.

I would like to add (create) objects using the entity manager to a table in MySQL (an online database). I checked thousands of videos but I can't resolve it.

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sk.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jpa</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>


    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**peristence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="sk.jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>sk.hibernate.model.Message</class>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>


            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://ujfnz0sxud23qruy:lqoN4PMPxWAAUjNEKuv8@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ujf**xud23qruy"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="YW**PR0569D"/>
            <!--<property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**APP class**

```
package sk.hibernate;

import sk.hibernate.model.Message;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =                     
            Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("sk.jpa");

        EntityManager entityManager = 
            entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(new Message("First message"));
        entityManager.persist(new Message("Second message"));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();    
    }
}
```

**Message**

```
package sk.hibernate.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVIE")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   // @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
   // @Column(name = "MESSAGE")

    private String message;

    private Date CREATE_DATE;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getCREATE_DATE() {
        return CREATE_DATE;
    }

    public void setCREATE_DATE(Date CREATE_DATE) {
        this.CREATE_DATE = CREATE_DATE;
    }
}
```

when i install mysql connector j was inside,trying to add in Java model structure-> dependecny and paste there and still not working.
**Problem**

```
"C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=52596:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\untitled\jpa\target\classes;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.4.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.7\byte-buddy-1.12.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.28\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Patrik Severín\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" sk.hibernate.App
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: sk.jpa]
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://ujfn**ud23qruy:l***AAUjNEKuv8@bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bkt9ucjj52rre9ut1cix]
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=ujfnz0sxud23qruy}
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
jan 29, 2022 11:27:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
jan 29, 2022 11:27:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at sk.hibernate.App.main(App.java:15)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at sk.hibernate.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
> DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

It means that you need to set the property **hibernate.dialect**.

You need to set `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`, because you have mysql-connector-java with version 8.0.28

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

Comment: nope problem is in free db what i have, maybe denied my java commands ,cause connect is acces denied.If use localhost offline its working,and mysql is conected but if want use java to create table doesnt work.. you know good free db what 100% work?